# Query DNS to find NAPTR in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dns

I have been having a lot of trouble finding a way to query the DNS to find the NAPTR in iOS.  There seem to be many relatively simple ways to resolve to an IP, but I specifically need to find all NAPTR records in a DNS lookup.  I'd prefer to do so without having to bring in any external libraries if at all possible.  If anyone has been able to do this (or something similar that I can extrapolate from) I'd appreciate any pointers.

All code must function in iOS 5.0+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using DNSServiceQueryRecord.

```
            DNSServiceRef sdRef;
            DNSServiceQueryRecord(&sdRef, 0, 0,
                                  "google.com",
                                  kDNSServiceType_NAPTR,
                                  kDNSServiceClass_IN,
                                  callback,
                                  NULL);

            DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef);
            DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef);
```

In actual use, I found that there was an issue where the app would hang indefinitely if there were no results, so I ended up having to adjust my code to add a timeout on the result.

```
/*
 Attempt to fetch the NAPTR from the stored server address.  Since iOS will continue waiting
 until told directly to stop (even if there is no result) we must set our own timeout on the
 request (set to 5 seconds).
 On success, the callback function is called.  On timeout, the kSRVLookupComplete notification
 is sent.
 */
- (void)attemptNAPTRFetch {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        DNSServiceRef sdRef;
        DNSServiceErrorType err;

        err = DNSServiceQueryRecord(&sdRef, 0, 0,
                                       [server cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]],
                                       kDNSServiceType_NAPTR,
                                       kDNSServiceClass_IN,
                                       callback,
                                       NULL);

        // This stuff is necessary so we don't hang forever if there are no results
        int dns_sd_fd = DNSServiceRefSockFD(sdRef);
        int nfds = dns_sd_fd + 1;
        fd_set readfds;
        struct timeval tv;
        int result;

        int stopNow = 0;
        int timeOut = 5; // Timeout in seconds

        while (!stopNow) {
           FD_ZERO(&readfds);
           FD_SET(dns_sd_fd, &readfds);
           tv.tv_sec = timeOut;
           tv.tv_usec = 0;

           result = select(nfds, &readfds, (fd_set*)NULL, (fd_set*)NULL, &tv);
           if (result > 0) {
               if(FD_ISSET(dns_sd_fd, &readfds)) {
                   err = DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef);
                   if (err != kDNSServiceErr_NoError){
                       NSLog(@"There was an error");
                   }
                   stopNow = 1;
               }
           }
           else {
               printf("select() returned %d errno %d %s\n", result, errno, strerror(errno));
               if (errno != EINTR) {
                   stopNow = 1;
                   postNotification(kSRVLookupComplete, nil);
               }
           }
        }

        DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef);
   });
}
```

Then, for the callback:

```
static void callback(DNSServiceRef sdRef,
          DNSServiceFlags flags,
          uint32_t interfaceIndex,
          DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
          const char *fullname,
          uint16_t rrtype,
          uint16_t rrclass,
          uint16_t rdlen,
          const void *rdata,
          uint32_t ttl,
          void *context) 
{    
    uint16_t order, pref;
    char flag;
    NSMutableString *service = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *replacement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    const char *data = (const char*)rdata;

    order = data[1];
    pref = data[3];
    flag = data[5];
    int i = 7;
    while (data[i] != 0){
        [service appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", data[i]]];
        i++;
    }
    i += 2;
    while(data[i] != 0){
        if(data[i] >= 32 && data[i] <= 127)
            [replacement appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", data[i]]];
        else
            [replacement appendString:@"."];
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"\nOrder: %i\nPreference: %i\nFlag: %c\nService: %@\nReplacement: %@\n", order, pref, flag, service, replacement);
}
```

This seems to do the trick for me.  You would of course do any other necessary work using all the parsed data in the callback or store the data somewhere to be used later.

Comment: How did you handle "DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef);            DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef);" being asynchronous.

I'm using the exact same way to retrieve NAPTR Records, when in debug mode processResult will stop and get all 5 records, but if I remove the breakpoints I'll get only 1 record and the main event loop will directly jump to DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef); I believe because it's async. How were you able to hold the main loop until ProcessResult finished retrieving all records.

Comment: I never experienced an issue the same as yours, but I did have a problem where if there were no results it would hang for forever.  I've added a snippet of code to my answer that shows how I manage it.  You might be able to make use of some/all of it to alleviate your issue.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That exactly did the trick! I have no idea how you got hold of these MACROs are what they actually do, any sort of documentation you recommend that might increase my knowledge with what you did there. I am indeed a n0ob

Comment: DNSServiceQueryRecord requests can be set to timeout after a system defined period by passing the kDNSServiceFlagsTimeout flag.

Comment: @kkoltzau using `kDNSServiceFlagsTimeout` is nonconfigurable and also stops a query even if it's met with success.  From Apple's documentation: `kDNSServiceFlagsTimeout`:  When passed to `DNSServiceQueryRecord` or `DNSServiceGetAddrInfo`, the query is stopped after a certain number of seconds have elapsed. **The time at which the query is stopped is determined by the system and cannot be configured by the user. The query is stopped irrespective of whether a response was given earlier or not.**

Comment: @Doc Yes, its is not configurable, but far more simplistic. Your sample also stops the query after a response via DNSServiceRefDeallocate so I believe that is equivalent.